# Using React with conditionals

Tags: reactjs

I have inherited a React UI. The UI is for filling out an application, based off of a value in a drop down I need to show different fields below that drop down and am stuck.

```
const yes_no_option = [
    "Yes",
    "No",
];
const [application, setField] = React.useState<ProposedInfo>({
    status: ""
});
<Modal 
  <form
    <FormField
    label = {<FormattedMessage id = "Is this an existing application?" />}
    >
      <Dropdown
        placeholder = {intl.formatMessage({ id: "Please select Yes or No"}))
        options = {yes_no_option.map((x: string) => ({label: x, value: x})))
        value = {application.status} 
        onItemSelect = {(e) => e && setField((prev) => ({...prev, status:e.value}))}
      />
   </FormField>
  </form>
</Modal>
```

And what I have tried is:

```
    if(application.status == "Yes") (with brackets and without)
        <FormField blah, blah/> (similarly defined to the above field)
    else
        <FormField abc/>
```

But the above prints everything directly to the UI. I also tried defining a very simple function since the React UI documentation had an example that I thought could be useful like so

```
    function switchFields(){
        const test = 1
        if test == 1:
           return <FormField blah, blah/>
        else:
           return <FormField abc />
    }
```

Which crashed the UI when I inserted it. I tried following the React documentation, but I couldn't get it to do what I needed.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're incorporating these various code snippets into your React component.  Can you update this to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The little function you wrote is the way to go ! However I think the code you return isn't valid. In particular around <FormField blah, blah/>. I don't think you can have an attribute with a comma.

Comment: I give it a 90% chance that you're writing this code directly into the HTML/JSX markup at the end, there. Your problem is that this isn't a bunch of code, but an implicitly-returned JSX *object*. If you want to include a conditional in it, you'll need to wrap it in curly brackets and use a ternary operator. This is one reason that I think people should always explicitly return these, so it's easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, yes this is a jsx object from what I can tell. I will try that

Answer (score 1):

I see what I was doing wrong when invoking the function I was not putting brackets around the function as Sameui alluded to.

```
function switchFields(name: string){
    if name == "Yes":
       return <FormField blah/>
    else:
       return <FormField abc />
}
```

later after I set the status of the application I inserted the below and got the desired results

```
<div >
    {switchFields(application.status)}
</div>
```